# Detect which button was clicked in a grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView (this one has 4 sections) and several rows each. I have programatically created 2 buttons in each of the cells.

This is how I am creating the `UITableViewCell`. In this code, I am trying to detect the indexPath.row and the indexPath.section of the button that was pressed and pass it to the method. How am I able to do this ?

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell ;//= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
}


NSString *docTitle = [currentDocument objectForKey:@"displayname"];

UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x+5, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
UILabel *cellTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cellView.frame.origin.x + 5, cellView.frame.origin.y + 5, cellView.frame.size.width - 10, 25)];
cellTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cellTitle.text = docTitle;
[cellView addSubview:cellTitle];

[cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];

UIButton *viewDocumentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[viewDocumentButton setTitle:@"View Online" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
viewDocumentButton.frame = CGRectMake(cellView.frame.origin.x + 5,       cellTitle.frame.origin.y + cellTitle.frame.size.height + 5, 150, 35);
[viewDocumentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openDocumentButtonPressedMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[viewDocumentButton setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:viewDocumentButton];

UIButton *downloadDocumentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[downloadDocumentButton setTitle:@"Download Document" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
downloadDocumentButton.frame = CGRectMake(cellView.frame.origin.x + 5, viewDocumentButton.frame.origin.y + viewDocumentButton.frame.size.height + 5, 150, 35);
[downloadDocumentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openDocumentButtonPressedMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[downloadDocumentButton setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:downloadDocumentButton];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;  
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You're giving your buttons tags, you can just check the tag in the action method. You should give the two buttons different action methods though. You should also uncomment out the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method so you take advantage of cell reuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additionally, you could...

```
- (IBAction)openDocumentButtonPressedMethod:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UIView *contentView = button.superview;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)contentView.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // do something with the indexPath
}
```

And if you wanted to use the same method to handle both button events, then you could use the tag on the button to distinguish between the two buttons.

```
if (button.tag == 1) {
    // do something with the indexPath view related
}
else {
    // do something with the indexPath download related
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of `UIButton`

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton 
{ /* indexPath, other stuff */ }
@end
```

Then implement

```
- (void)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

to do something with the `indexPath` and other stuff before invoking the `super` for this method.

When you create the button, provide `indexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `openDocumentButtonPressedMethod:` method, do

```
CGPoint pointInTableView = [self.tableView convertPoint:sender.bounds.origin fromView:sender];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTableView];
```